# Why is Mother Yolanda a Yoda knockoff?

Tags: star-wars, webcomics, sister-claire

Mother Yolanda of "Sister Claire" webcomic seems to be **a very deliberate and in-your-face** Yoda knockoff (in the order of specificity of traits):

- She is a leader of a religious order
- She is shown as being very old and small
- Her name is **Yo**-lan-**da**
- She kinda looks like Yoda, down to greenish skin

  [image]
- Always speak in Yoda's Grammar, she does.

**Why?**

None of the rest of that webcomic appears to pay any explicit (or otherwise) homage to Star Wars (or any other speculative fiction that I'm aware of, for that matter). The comic is magical fantasy, not SciFi or Space Opera.

**Did the comic creator address this somehow in comments/interviews/etc...?**

Comment: Well... why not?

Comment: @jwodder - see the second from the last paragraph for "why"

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Why is a Yoda reference more puzzling than any other pop culture reference? Is there some rule that you can only do references to sci-fi if your comic is sci-fi? According to http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Webcomic/SisterClaire it's full of homages and references, probably just based on whatever the creator thinks is cool: "Easter Egg: Yamino loves throwing in homages and references for readers to find. Some are more subtle, others are direct homages, such as the Powerpuff Girls 10th anniversary page, featuring Claire and the PPG sharing a cake."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because [Sister Claire](http://www.sisterclaire.com/) is full of homages to other media.  As a longtime fan, the artist, Yamino is constantly slipping in nods to her favourite media.  Star Wars, Big O, Avatar: The Last Airbender and Legend of Korra, Harry Potter, Rose of Versailles, Panty & Stocking with Garterbelt, Utena, the Bat-family (Batman, Batwoman, Batgirl, Robin etc.), Mario games, Sailor Moon, Snorks, Azumanga Daioh and even other webcomics have references throughout the comic.

A lot of comics and other media are full of shoutouts.  In Farscape a running gag is John Crichton constantly making media references no one else gets to stay sane.  Hercules/Xena used this regularly for comic effect.  Deadpool comics are full of fourth-wall-breaking references to DC comics and other media.  Big Bang Theory is almost nothing but references with a laugh track.  Looney Tunes and its spinoffs (Tiny Toons, Animaniacs, etc.) referential inserts far outweighed its original content.

It is the nature of media to incorporate other media to act as cultural reference points.  And media created by fans is far more likely to do this, especially if their audience is other fans.

Other Star Wars nods include:

- Energia - Analogous to the force, that both the Nuns and Witches wield in different ways similar to Jedi and Sith.  It binds all living things together
- Title of Chapter 7 borrows from Luke training on Dagobah.
- The mystery around Clair's birth and destiny making her analogous to Anakin.
- And of course Sister Yolanda

All in all the Star Wars references are a little less prevalent than say Avatar, or Rose of Versailles but they are there.

Comment: Can you please provide specific examples of Star Wars homages?

Comment: What in general culture or just this comic?  I mean the author specifically said she was including parodies of Star Wars in the comic three years ago  http://yamino.tumblr.com/post/3408770968/ok-i-was-looking-up-star-wars-clips-to-parody-in.  And other than inspecting every page of the last 6 years of the comic I doubt you would get a comprehensive list.

As for other media, are you liiking for a comprehensive list of all Star Wars homages?

Either way that seems a little out of the scope of this site.

Comment: I'm not looking for a comprehensive list. Author's statement + 2 examples of homages would be 100% of what I would expect of a perfect answer, since my impression was that Yolanda was the one and only SW homage in that comic.

Comment: BTW, that Tumblr link seems inconclusive. Author said "Ok, I was looking up Star Wars clips to parody in Sister Claire" - but didn't state that they DID parody it.